# Combine stackbox with multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn, booktabs, adjustbox

I am trying to keep my multicolumn table as small as possible and wanted to have the first row stacked. However, when I try to use the \stackbox option the name gets continued on to the next one which is not included in the multicolumn. I added a picture and my code for clarity.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{XXX}
     \label{tab:PECs}
     \begin{adjustbox}{center,max width=\linewidth}
      \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \toprule   
        {} & \multicolumn{2}{l}\stackbox{Durchschnittlicher Verbrauch\\ pro Woche in \%} \\
      \cmidrule{2-3} 
       \small ABs & \small {Reaktor 1 und 2} & \small {Reaktor 3 und 4}  \\
      \midrule
\small CPX    & -83,7481154     & -47,2712685     \\
\small ETM    & -5,65120427     & 11,0344732      \\
\small ETM-H\textsubscript{2}O & -1,71578858     & 15,4926193      \\
\small RXM    & -18,4440202     & -17,1456878     \\
\small SMX    & -5,37574324     & 14,2887729      \\
\small TCC    & -70,281838      & -49,0324859     \\
\small TMP    & -11,4882087     & -9,21633665     \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}\\
```

Comment: Please, can you put a minimal working example and not a snippet code?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It would be helpful if you extend your code to a full compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  That will provide a basis for a helper to experiment without guessing.

Answer (score 1):

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a complete small document (see @Barbara Beeton comment).
- I guess that table is in two column document
- for cell with two lines text I would not use `adjustbox` package and environment, this can be simpler to obtain with for example with prescribed cell width or use of `\makecell` defined in the package of the same name
- For your table I would use `tabularray`, `booktabs`,`siunitx` and `mhchem` packages. With them the table code is simpler and compilation result is nicer:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text filler

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{XXX}
\label{tab:PECs}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec  = {@{} l *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=-2.8}]} @{}},
                 rowsep   = 1pt,
                 row{1,2} = {guard, font=\small\bfseries, m}
                 }
      \toprule
             &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {Durchschnittlicher Verbrauch\\ pro Woche in \%}
                                &                   \\
      \cmidrule{2-3}
ABs          & Reaktor 1 und 2  & Reaktor 3 und 4   \\
      \midrule
CPX          & -83,7481154      & -47,2712685       \\
ETM          &  -5,65120427     & 11,0344732        \\
ETM-\ce{H2O}& -1,71578858       & 15,4926193        \\
RXM          & -18,4440202      & -17,1456878       \\
SMX          & -5,37574324      & 14,2887729        \\
TCC          & -70,281838       & -49,0324859       \\
TMP          & -11,4882087      & -9,21633665       \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
However, if you for some reason persist on your way to write a table, than you need to add missing `}` in multi column cell:

```
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\stackbox{Durchschnittlicher Verbrauch\\ pro Woche in \%}} \\
```

(observe two `}}` at end of cell)

Result of compilation is than:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `\stackbox` is, but implementing it is not difficult.

You *never* need `adjustbox` around a table.

In the following I show that `\normalsize` is good enough for this table and how you can make it to be as wide as the `\columnwidth`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\sisetup{locale=DE}

\newcommand{\stackbox}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htp!]

\caption{XXX}\label{tab:PECs}

\centering\small

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=-2.8]
  S[table-format=-2.8]
  @{}
}
\toprule   
ABs & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\stackbox[t]{Durchschnittlicher Verbrauch\\ pro Woche in \%}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3} 
& {Reaktor 1 und 2} & {Reaktor 3 und 4}  \\
\midrule
CPX           & -83,7481154     & -47,2712685     \\
ETM           & -5,65120427     & 11,0344732      \\
ETM-\ch{H2 O} & -1,71578858     & 15,4926193      \\
RXM           & -18,4440202     & -17,1456878     \\
SMX           & -5,37574324     & 14,2887729      \\
TCC           & -70,281838      & -49,0324859     \\
TMP           & -11,4882087     & -9,21633665     \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{table}[htp!]

\caption{XXX}\label{tab:PECs}

\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% let TeX compute

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=-2.8]
  S[table-format=-2.8]
  @{}
}
\toprule   
ABs & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\stackbox[t]{Durchschnittlicher Verbrauch\\ pro Woche in \%}} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3} 
& {Reaktor 1 und 2} & {Reaktor 3 und 4}  \\
\midrule
CPX           & -83,7481154     & -47,2712685     \\
ETM           & -5,65120427     & 11,0344732      \\
ETM-\ch{H2 O} & -1,71578858     & 15,4926193      \\
RXM           & -18,4440202     & -17,1456878     \\
SMX           & -5,37574324     & 14,2887729      \\
TCC           & -70,281838      & -49,0324859     \\
TMP           & -11,4882087     & -9,21633665     \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]